# TypeError: promise.then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).catch is not a function in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Im getting this error and i dont know how to solve it.
In a node js server, i'm using some .then() function on a promise and at the end i placed a .catch() function that for some reason is not recognized.
I have seen in many places in tutorials that this is how an error is handled. 
I'm not using any external libraries.

The error :

```
 TypeError: promise.then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).catch is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
exports.joinAlbum = function(req, res){


var promise = Album.findOne().where({'shortId': req.body.shortId}).exec(); // Returns a promise


promise.then(function(albumDoc){
    console.log('Then #1');

    .....

    }
    return albumDoc.save();  // Returns a promise
})



.then(function(albumDoc){
    console.log('Then #2');

    .....

    return User.findById(req.body.userId).exec(); // Returns a promise
})


.then(function(userDoc){
    console.log('Then #3');

     ........

    return userDoc.save();  // Returns a promise
})

//  Return a response
.then(function(savedUserDoc){
    console.log('Then #4');
    return res.status(200).json({success: true}); 
})

    //Error handler
.catch(function(err){
    console.log('Catch #1');
    console.log(err);
    res.status(200).json({success: false});
});
}
```

If .catch() is not the correct way to handle promise error, what do you suggest? Im trying to avoid using external libraries and prefer using native javascript

**EDIT: solution**

I added a npm module called blue-bird that helped me solve this.

Comment: `.catch()` is for a `try` block. If an error is returned in the `then` block, throw a new error

Comment: If the current [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33678090/691711) isn't helpful, please say what kind of Promise `Album.findOne().where()` returns, as in what library if not **ES6**.  Maybe include what version of node.js you are using as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you're using Mongoose, which returns its own Promise, not the ES6 promise which includes a catch function. A mongoose Promise has no catch function. You can overwrite the default Promise that Mongoose uses, fortunately:

http://eddywashere.com/blog/switching-out-callbacks-with-promises-in-mongoose/

Comment: I didnt know that these are different promises! Thank you