# (...).then is not a function in node (expressJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm using a library of promises [hope.js](https://github.com/soyjavi/hope).
The problem is sometimes it returns me the following error: 
`(...).then is not a function`.
I don't know why, and I had to do a lot of tinkering.

The code of the methods that work seems like that of those without, the only diference is in this case, I am using other library: [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async).

My code is as follows:

Controller:

```
userstoryservice.deleteTaskByIdRemovedUS(userstoryexists)
  .then(function(error, arraysresult) {
      if (error)
        response.status(error.code).json({
          message: error.message
        });

      else
        response.status(200).json({
          message: 'deleted successfully});

        });
```

My service:

```
exports.deleteTaskByIdRemovedUS = function deleteTaskByIdRemovedUS(userstoryexists) {
  var promise = new Hope.Promise();
  var Task = mongoose.model('Task');
  var obj = {};

  obj.arrTasksIdsRemoved = [];
  obj.arrTasksIdsRemovedErrors = [];

  async.each(userstoryexists.tasks,
    function(item, callback) {
      var query = {
        _id: item.id
      };

      Task.deleteTaskById(item.id).then(function(error) {
        if (error) {
          obj.arrTasksIdsRemovedErrors.push(item.id);
        } else {
          obj.arrTasksIdsRemoved.push(item.id);
        }

        callback(); //required
      });
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error:' + err);
        return promise.done(err, null);
      } else {
        return promise.done(null, obj);
      }
    });
  } else {
    return promise.done(null, obj);
  }
  return promise;
};
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is that `callback ()` function being called?

Comment: what `callback()`? The `foreach callback()`?

Comment: Don't use `async.js` together with promises!

Comment: I thought it might affect, but it is not true, because I have other method with `async.js` and `promise` and it works. Any way, I need synchronize calls, because I need delete all tasks inside of userstory and then return the response to client. How could it?

Comment: I know that it works if I do all in controller, but I don't like it.

Comment: do not return the promise.done();

you have already returned the promise from the function. btw using Hope or other libraries is useless over node since node has native promises and you can avoid promises all together as you are using async.js anyways.

Comment: What do you mean with does not return `promise.done ()`?
`promise.done()` is necessary to be returned although then you put `return promise`. If you mean that, it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677900/typeerror-promise-then-then-then-then-catch-is-not-a-functi) that says why this happens.

The problem is that mongoose return its own promises, not the `ES6 promise`, and this causes a conflict.

Also the owner of the library answered me, and told me the same and how to fix it: [link](https://github.com/soyjavi/hope/issues/5).

Thank you all for your interest.